# Set environment variable in bat file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I tried to use a library (mapnik )and the python binding with it.

The library is installed at `D:\install\gis\mapnik-v2.2.0`, then I add the following variable to the environment variable through the control panel:

```
PATH: D:\install\gis\mapnik-v2.2.0\bin;D:\install\gis\mapnik-v2.2.0\lib


PYTHONPATH:D:\install\gis\mapnik-v2.2.0\python\2.7\site-packages
```

Then I run:

```
python
>>import mapnik
```

This worked.

However, I do not want to set the variable to the global environment variable, so I tried to create a bat file like this:

setup_mapnik_path.bat:

```
SET mapnik_path=D:\install\gis\mapnik-v2.2.0;
SET PATH=%PATH%;%mapnik_path%\lib;%mapnik_path%\bin;
SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%mapnik_path%\python\2.7\site-packages;
```

Then once I tried to run a script who use mapnik I will run the bat first:

```
setup_mapnik_path.bat
python
>>import mapnik
```

But I will get error:

```
ImportError: No module named mapnik
```

Screenshot:http://pbrd.co/1lUk1F5

What's the problem?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9546462/2032568) is the issue.

Comment: Do you mean that the latest set variables will not affect immediately? But I have find that some open source project would set the environment variable  in the shell, for example, the tomcat :http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/bin/catalina.bat

Comment: Have you tried setting the variables as you are doing and opening a new shell and starting python? It was just a suggestion, I haven't used Windows in a long time to know how it should happen.

Comment: Since the variables are set through the bat file, I have to run it in the command prompt, I want the variables take affect in the current prompt, once I open a new prompt and do not run the bat again, the variables will not work.

Answer (score 0):

What you listed as your script:

```
setup_mapnik_path.bat
python
>>import mapnik
```

just can NOT be a script, because ">>import mapnik" should be a keyboard input, right?

You script should be like this:

```
call setup_mapnik_path.bat
python
```

Previous script call the first Batch file that define the variables, then *return* and execute python. After that, you enter ">>import mapnik" via keyboard.

Comment: Say that, I have several .py script to run which need set the variable first, so what should I do? for example, there  is a script named `run.py`, do I have to  modify this script?